# SQL command not properly ended? How to use cursor in oracle?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, flat-file

I am trying to save to file on my computer but I am getting this error for the select statement.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE export_cust(dir VARCHAR2, file_name VARCHAR2, tblname VARCHAR2) 
IS
CURSOR cur IS SELECT * FROM tblname AS row_value;
file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN  
  -- Open the file for writing
file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(UPPER(dir), file_name, 'w', 32767);

-- Export rows one by one 
 FOR rec IN cur LOOP 
   -- All columns were concatenated into single value in SELECT
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file, rec.row_value);
END LOOP;

 UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file);
  END;
  /
```

I want the user to to choose a directory, filename as well as the table they want to export from. Also how do I utilize row by row processing in oracle 11g. I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly here

Comment: One problem is in line 3, `tblname AS row_value;`.  The `AS` keyword is only supported in the `SELECT` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.  Remove `AS` and it should work.

Comment: I removed the AS but I'm getting table does not exist and loop index variable 'REC' use is invalid

Answer (score 0):

**First** you should use DIRECTORY object to write files. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245750/sql-command-not-properly-ended-how-to-use-cursor-in-oracle) for further details. Pass the diretory name as a paramater.

```
CREATE DIRECTORY tmp_dir AS '<your path here>';
```

The user need to have priviledges on the directory

```
GRANT READ, WRITE  ON DIRECTORY tmp_dir TO <use name>;
```

**Secondly** concatenate the column data in a single row string (here trivial example - you may need a more advanced logik e.g.to escape special characters.

For a table like this

```
 create table tab as
 select 'xxxxx' as col1, 'yyyy' as col2 from dual;
```

you may use

```
 SELECT col1||','||col2 as row_value FROM tab;
```

So if you parametrize the table name this will work only if all tables contain `col1`and `col2` - otherwise you'll need to pass additional paramaters to define how to build the `row_value`

**Finally** to parametrize the table name in a cursor you need a [dynamic cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm) 
This leads to following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE export_cust(dir VARCHAR2, file_name VARCHAR2, tblname VARCHAR2) 
IS
  TYPE TabCurTyp  IS REF CURSOR;
  cur    TabCurTyp;
  row_value    varchar2(4000);
  file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN  

 file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(UPPER(dir), file_name, 'w', 32767);
 OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT col1||'',''||col2 as row_value FROM '|| tblname;
 LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO row_value;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file, row_value);  
  END LOOP; 

 UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file);
END;
/
```

You may also check for some existing *CSV Exporter* scripts.